# Trouble joining tables while inserting them into new table.

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

Right now I am trying to join information from two different tables into one new table.

Here's what I have now.

```
insert into invoices_paid(InvoiceNumber,InvoiceDate,InvoiceTotal) 
select InvoiceNumber,InvoiceDate,InvoiceTotal
from Invoices
insert into invoices_paid(AccountNo, InvoiceLineItemAmount, InvoiceLineItemDescription) 
select AccountNo, InvoiceLineItemAmount, InvoiceLineItemDescription 
From InvoiceLineItems
```

Pictures to help.[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dRRX.jpg)

I need the information in the red box to match up with their respective information with the columns on the left. I'm pretty new with joins but I think I'm close. Can anyone help?

Comment: That screenshot looks very much like SQL Server Management Studio. Tagged wrong RDMS?

Answer (score 0):

Join the Invoices and InvoiceLineItems table on InvoiceNumber, and use that as the data source for the SELECT clause of the INSERT statement.  Such as:

```
insert into invoices_paid (InvoiceNumber,InvoiceDate,InvoiceTotal,
    AccountNo, InvoiceLineItemAmount, InvoiceLineItemDescription)
select
    inv.InvoiceNumber,InvoiceDate,InvoiceTotal,
    AccountNo, InvoiceLineItemAmount, InvoiceLineItemDescription
from 
    Invoices as inv
    inner join InvoiceLineItems as li on li.InvoiceNumber = inv.InvoiceNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert the values in the new table using the select to find the values from other tables you are considring also you have to make a condition and consider joining two tables based on the condition you have to make rows:

```
insert into invoices_paid(InvoiceNumber,InvoiceDate
 ,InvoiceTotal,AccountNo, InvoiceLineItemAmount, InvoiceLineItemDescription)
 values (select i.InvoiceNumber,i.InvoiceDate,i.InvoiceTotal
 , b.AccountNo, b.InvoiceLineItemAmount, b.InvoiceLineItemDescription
 from Invoices as i join InvoiceLineItems
 as b where i.InvoiceNumber = b.AccountNo )
```